# Submit form and send data through AJAX at the same time?

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox

Let's say I have a simple form, with a select combobox and a table that has a checkbox for each row, to choose the rows you want.

Now, on the server-side, I need to associate all the items selected from the table (using the checkbox for each row), with the item selected in the combobox.

I know the value in the combobox will be submitted with the form, but how can I send all the selected elements from the table? do I have to use AJAX or something? or is it possible to do it via POST/GET?

Comment: No, you can simply get the checked items in a regular form post.  Is it not working for you?

Comment: i haven't tried it out yet actually, but how do i know on the server side **which** elements are selected from the table? can i put all the checkboxes in the table in an array? something like `<input type="checkbox" name="clients[client_id]"/>`, and send that var via POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form needs to enclose (be an anscestor of) both the table and the combo box. 
The table row checkboxes should all look like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rows[]" value="ROW ID"/>
```

And then on the server side you'll get, in addition to the combobox value, `$_POST['rows']` as an array containing the ids of the checked rows.

Comment: will that give me only the selected checboxes, or all of them?